# React native tensorflowjs very slow prediction

Tags: react-native, keras, deep-learning, lstm, tensorflow.js

So I made and trained my own model in keras. Here's the model (6~ million params):

[image]

I converted it into a tfjs graphmodel. And implemented it into my react native app. Here's the converting command:

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_saved_model --output_format=tfjs_graph_model --weight_shard_size_bytes 60000000 /Some/Path /Some/Other/Path
```

**My problem is that it takes a whole 2 minutes for 1 prediction** when for my app purposes I need real time application speed. But on colab the prediction takes 400ms. Here's the prediction code:

```
let input = tf.randomNormal([50, 6]);
input = tf.reshape(input,[-1,50,6]);
const res = model.predict(input);
//const res = await this._model.executeAsync(input);
console.log(res.data());
```

**So is there something I'm doing wrong with tfjs and the conversion ?**

**Is my model just too big ? And even if I make my model smaller is there any optimisation processes I can use here ?**

**And for this kind of model what 'size' would allow me to have a quick prediction time?**

Update : so the amount of parameters for my model was absurd.

Through thorough remodeling and changes, I've made a 4k params model (still LSTM based) converted into tfjs graph model. The model.json file weighs 40.5kB and the shard file weighs   18.5kB.
The model loads quickly but there's still the problem of prediction time. For such a small model my android emulator still takes 1 second for each prediction. So my question remains is there any way to make this execution faster?

Comment: How big is your model? In theory it is a matrix multiplication the bottleneck I can imagine is memory. Did you try to profile it?

Comment: It would be useful to know what hardware your computer is using. Collabs usually use high performant GPUs suitable for AI. It would also be good to know you have webgl support? Try chrome://gpu.

Comment: @partizanos i dont understand what you mean by how big. You mean in memory? haven't tried profiling yet.

Comment: @danielskantze It's for an app so the important harware is the phone. But my computer doesnt have a gpu but has 16 gb RAM and i7 4790 CPU.

Comment: @HadrienRothea I mean memory. The input is 300 dimensions and nomatter how huge the model is at the end it is a matrix. I am a bit surprised that the number of neurons is that high. (much bigger than 300). May I ask how you chose the number of neurons per layer? Also how do you load your model and what is its size in MB?

Comment: Also just to be sure it's not initialization botteleneck issue, does the second prediction takes also 2 minutes ?

Answer (score 1):

Your model is definitely too large.

Smartphone RAM and GPU memory sizes are much smaller than whatever Google is offering on Colab. Usually the neural net can be held entirely in the RAM, so math and retrieve times are fast there. When the memory being loaded gets too large, the model has to shift data from phone storage to memory whenever it wants to do a matrix multiplication, which is all the time. This is a very slow load.

To speed it up, make it smaller. There should be a breakpoint where the model begins to fit properly in memory and you get a big jump in speed. I warn you though, if you want it to work for all kinds of devices you'll need to make it really small, around ~100k params.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I've made a lot of changes to my model and the data so that i could cut the absurd amout of params. I now have a 4k params model which i converted to graph model to make it faster. Yet it still takes 1 whole second for each prediction (on android emulator). Is there anything i can still do to make it faster. I mean 4k is the lowest i can go and i cant reduce the model more or it wont make any sense.

Comment: Great job reducing it! If it takes 1 second and it takes 400ms on Colab I'd say you've done everything you can to make it run on android in real-ish time. Mobile is usually slower than desktop, and those Colab computers are quite beefy.